# iOS ZipArchive compile error:invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires iOS 5.0 or later)

Tags: ios, xcode4, zip, objective-c++, unzip

I'm using zipArchive library in Xcode to integrate into my project to do unzip operation. And I got following compile error message. my question is how can i resolve this compile issue?

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. download ziparchive from http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/:
2. create a new xcode project (just use single view template), select ios4.3 simulator
3. drag the download unzipped folder to project, and select "copy item..." ,"create group", and check the "add to targets"

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

Compiled error with error message : invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires iOS 5.0 or later)

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?

mac, xcode4.5.1, iphone4.3 simulator  (it's OK in iOS6)

Comment: +1 for providing "steps to reproduce".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `ZipArchive.mm` from the ziparchive project has the suffix `.mm` for *Objective-C++* files. However, the file does not seem to contain any C++ code. After renaming it to `ZipArchive.m` I could compile it even for iOS 4.3 deployment target.

---

A different solution of the problem can be found in the [Xcode 4.5 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW174):

> Projects created using this Xcode release use the new libc++
> implementation of the standard C++ library. The libc++ library is
> available only on iOS 5.0 and later and OS X 10.7 and later.
>
> To enable deployment on earlier releases of iOS and OS X in your
> project, set the C++ Standard Library build setting to libstdc++ (Gnu
> C++ standard library).

Comment: Following your instruction, it could pass compile. However, when I include #import "ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h" in .pch file, compile error become many.

Comment: the first erro message is: Parse Issue Expected identifier or '('

Comment: @LiangWang: It is almost impossible to tell the reason for this error without seeing the source code. If you can put a small sample project on a server and post the link here, I would look at it and try to help. Otherwise you have to show at least the complete contents of the .pch file.

Comment: @LiangWang: I might have found the reason for your problem: You have to put `#import "ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h"` between `#ifdef __OBJC__` and `#endif` in the .pch file, otherwise you get these errors. - I hope this helps, please let me know!

Comment: Thousands thanks for your help @Martin R. It works now. You know I have been in the trouble for several days you have given me a big help.

Comment: could you let me know why need to be included into between #ifdef __OBJC__ and #endif?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @LiangWang: Because the .pch file is also used for compiling the plain C files (zip.c, unzip.c, ...). In that case the compiler is not in "Objective-C" mode and therefore does not recognize `@class` etc.

Comment: sorry about that.I began to visit this site 2 weeks and i'm new. Thanks a lot for your help.